# How to read the content of Tableue graphs in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The graph on the website looks like :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4QWT.png)

I need to read the pop up data when i hover on the graph. I cannot do inspect element on the pop up data.
In HTML i can see below code:

```
<div id="view5561218686836924094_14132909152772909395" class="tab-tvView tvimagesNS" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); left: 20px; top: 25px; width: 192px; height: 230px;">
<div class="tvScrollContainer tvmodeRectSelect" style="cursor: pointer; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 192px; height: 230px;">
<div class="tvBackgroundContainer" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
<div class="tvimagesContainer" style="width: 192px; height: 230px;">
<canvas class="tabCanvas tab-widget" width="192" height="230" style="width: 192px; height: 230px;"/>
<canvas class="tabCanvas tab-widget" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 192px; height: 230px;" width="192" height="230"/>
</div>
<div class="tvdrag" style="display: none;">
<div class="tvdrag_image" style="display: none;"/>
<div class="tvdrag_mask" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
<div class="tvdrag" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why can't you acces it? Is there a exception, which exception? How do you try to acces it? Code Snippet? Please read, how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)